# NPM del throws ENOTEMPTY error when running from a set of gulp tasks

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a list of tasks in `gulpfile.js`. One of them is `clean`, which is supported by [`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del):

```
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del([
        'dist/**'
    ], cb);
});
```

Which is executed in a queue:

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'templates', 'styles']);
```

When I run it as a single task, like `gulp clean`, it works fine and removes the whole folder as expected.

When I just run `gulp` to run the default set of tasks, it throws this:

```
[15:55:45] 'clean' errored after 136 ms
[15:55:45] Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/sergeybasharov/WebstormProjects/myproject/dist'
```

How can I avoid it and make it clean the folder as needed? Should I do anything with the callback, like putting the rest tasks in it?

Comment: You can try with sync method of del.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a little old, but I just ran into this issue.

For me, the problem had to do with dependencies. Gulp didn't know to wait for my clean task before starting my copy task.

After a quick read of the gulp documentation on [running tasks in series](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md) it was obvious that I had to add my 'clean' task as a dependency to any task that could get in it's way, like copy or concat.